# C# Expression to return TSQL Contains keyword

Tags: c#, sql, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following code:

```
public Expression FilterString(string property, string Value, ParameterExpression parameter)
{
    var getname = Expression.Property(parameter, property);

    var toLower = Expression.Call(getname, "ToLower", null, null);

    var contains = Expression.Call(toLower, "Contains", null, new[] { Expression.Constant(Value.ToString().ToLower()) });

    //This will result in "LOWER(Body) LIKE '%abc123% " but I need "CONTAINS(Body, 'abc123')"

    return contains;
}

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Message), "message");
var expressionFilter = myclass.FilterString("Body","abc123", parameter);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expressionFilter, parameter);

//Apply lambda to EF query object
query = query.Where((Expression<Func<Message, bool>>)lambda);
```

This produces a TSQL LIKE statement but I'd like it to do a CONTAINS statement.

Is there anyway that I can modify the above `FilterString` method to make it do that?

Comment: Contains is not part of SQL99 -- that is why it is not included.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can using vanilla EF, at least according to the source here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/EntitySql/AST/BuiltInKind.cs

You'd have to add Contains to the AST and generate it. [Here's a basic tutorial on DBProviders.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789836%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks what do you mean by AST?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not exactly what you want, but you should be able to get the results you want pretty easily by allowing yourself to step out of LINQ and querying the database directly:

```
MyDbContext.Database
.SqlQuery<MyTable>("select * from [MyTable] where contains(Body, @p0), "abc123")
```

Comment: Thanks. Issue I have is I send an IQueryable through some filter code like the above based on a operator,key and value stored in the DB eg/Equals,Body,'abc'